# How can I achieve same functionality as in the Ajax.BeginForm in .Net Core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an older website that use .Net Framework and this form in a partial view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "MainLayout",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith,
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "searchResultsDivInPartialView",
        OnSuccess = "OnAjaxSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnAjaxFailure"
    }))
    {

        if (Model.ShowMore)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("Partials/SiteLayout/_ShowMore");
        }
    }
```

As I understand the Ajax.BeginForm is not supported in .Net core 6. Is there any way I can achieve the same functionality in a .Net Core 6 webb application

Comment: AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax and other library could achieve the same thing, you could try it.

Comment: I thought of that too, but it has not been updated in a long time....

Comment: I think you could try it, the codes of the beginajaxform doesn't change much.